Unfollow on edit? Please revert
Over the last few weeks I've noticed that when I follow a post, it can automatically be unfollowed upon an edit of that post - at least that applies to questions as per my recent experience with this one on medicalsciences. Of course, I followed it again right away.
Expected/desired behaviour: A followed post should remain followed until the follower unfollows it manually.
Note: If this is not a bug but a feature, then please consider this a [feature-request].

It's a visual bug. The in-page reload of the question resets the label of the button. But if you refresh the page, you'd see you're still following it. In general, there are a lot of problems with the in-place reload because seems there the content returned from the server on page load and on question reload is different.
